# How to inject JavaScript into root layout from view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 3` with the `Razor view engine`.

I have a layout view called `_Root.cshtml`.  The HTML markup looks like this:

```
<body>

     <div id="hd"></div>

     @RenderBody()

     <div id="ft"></div>

     @RenderSection("JavaScriptBodySection", false)

</body>
```

The `@RenderBody()` is there because the layout differs depending on what view you are at.  The `JavaScriptBodySection` is where I want all my JavaScript to go that is used by a view (injected by the view).

I have another layout that uses this _Root layout called `_Lr.cshtml`.  The HTML markup looks like this:

```
<div id="bd">

  <!-- Layout code here -->

  @RenderBody()

</div>
```

Then finally my Index view uses this _Lr layout and the markup looks like this:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Lr.cshtml";
}

<div class="main-content">
     <!-- Some stuff here -->
</div>

@section JavaScriptBodySection
{
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

It is complaining that there is no JavaScriptBodySection in _Lr.  I don't want it here because then my JavaScript is beneath my div with id bd, I want it just before the closing body tag (in _Root).  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `_Lr.cshtml` you need to redefine the section:

```
<div id="bd">
    <!-- Layout code here -->
    @RenderBody()
</div>
@section JavaScriptBodySection {
    @RenderSection("JavaScriptBodySection", false)
}
```

This obviously assumes that `_Lr.cshtml` derives from `Root.cshtml` (nested layouts).

Comment: Yes it works.  But I don't understand why _Lr has a RenderSection as you mentioned above.  Does it mean that the _Root must render it seeing that there is also a RenderSection?